# Почему PictureBox не меняет цвет

Tags: c#

Скажите, вот если не нажимать кнопку "Без Сохранения", то при изменении цвета заднего фона, он меняется, но если я нажму "Без Сохранения"(новый рисунок), то он больше не меняет цвет. Вот код который выполняется при нажатии на "Без Сохранения"

```
        private Graphics grap1;
        private void безСохраненияToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grap1.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor);
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
```

**А вот код изменения цвета фона**

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (colorDialog2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.BackColor = colorDialog2.Color;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А где код другой функции? В отладчике посмотрите, скорее всего, у нового рисунка BackColor - не задан.

Comment: Изменил первый пост, добавил функцию(при нажатии на кнопку) изменения цвета фона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам давно уже с виндовcформами не работал, но МСДН говорит попробовать как-то так:

```
pictureBox1.Invalidate();
pictureBox1.Update();
```

**UPD.** Проблема заключается в том, что мы заливаем канву (Graphics) каким либо цветом, а она перекрывает фоновый цвет PictureBox, т.к. находится над ним, соответственно, следующий код решает проблему:

```
private void безСохраненияToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grap1.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Не помогает, цвет не меняется.

Comment: А можете исходник куда-нить кинуть? Сейчас студии под рукой нет, а завтра могу днем посмотреть.

Comment: http://narod.ru/disk/31594037001/test.rar.html вот.

Answer (score 2):

Взял ваш проект и добавил строчку: `pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;` У меня смена фона не отвалилась почему-то.

```
private void безСохраненияToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
            grap1.Clear(Color.White);            
            grap1 = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            bitmap1 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            grap1 = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap1);
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
```

Оффтоп, но по теме. Рисование кривых можно сделать так:

```
    int oldX, oldY;
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        paint = true;
        oldX = e.X;
        oldY = e.Y;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        paint = false;            
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "X: " + e.X.ToString();
        toolStripStatusLabel3.Text = "Y: " + e.Y.ToString();
            if (paint)
            {                    
                Pen pen = new Pen(colorDialog1.Color);
                pen.Width = 2.0f; // тут переделаете
                grap1.DrawLine(pen, new Point(oldX, oldY), new Point(e.X, e.Y));            
                pictureBox1.Image = bitmap1;
                oldX = e.X;
                oldY = e.Y;
            }
    }
```

А еще если в конструкторе формы добавить:

```
 public Form2()
            {
               ...
               grap1.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
               grap1.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            }
```

Тогда линии будут рисоваться сглаженными,  используя встроенный антиалиасинг. Эти строчки нужно повторить если будете в другом месте инициализировать повторно grap1.

Comment: :) неужели просто строчку пропустил?! Ведь в вопросе именно так и написано. От меня +1

Comment: опять исправил, все-таки вторая строчка как оказалось была не к месту :) надо лучше сразу чистить контекст нужным цветом, если я правильно понял автора

Comment: У меня почему-то не работает, вот я порисовал, сменил задний цвет... после нажал Без Сохранения, цвет поменялся на белый, после я захотел поменять цвет например на красный, а он не меняется.

Comment: В итоге помогло то, что предложил invincible? 
Кстати дополнил ответ :)

Comment: Нет... у меня просто тупо второй раз цвет не меняется... уже сотни роликов просмотрел, не помогает, тут уже 2 человека пытаются помочь, и не помогает(когда вы качали проект, и изменяли его, то у вас все менялось?)

Comment: Ну да не сработало. Попробуйте сейчас что получится (снова обновил пост).

Comment: У меня так тоже работает, только в функцию изменения фона нужно добавить строчку, иначе фон обновляется только если что-то нарисовать:

       if (colorDialog2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)  
                {  
                    pictureBox1.BackColor = colorDialog2.Color;  
                    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap1;  
                    pictureBox1.Invalidate();  
                }

Answer (score 0):

Делай так:

```
if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {              
            graphics.Clear(colorDialog1.Color);
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
```